# How to prevent data from being added if it already exists in database

Tags: asp.net, sql

I want the user to register in a website & if his email already exists his data shouldn't be added.

Now this is the function I use:

```
IF exists( SELECT        SU_ID, SU_Email
           FROM            SystemUser
           WHERE        (SU_Email = @email)
           )
Begin
    return 0
END
else
begin
    return -1
end
```

but even when the select statement returns a value it doesn't return 0 & returns -1. 
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: make the email table primary key, voila done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we write a function we also declare a return variable, you are missing that, Follow the below code

```
Create function CheckUser(@Email @Varchar(50))
RETURNS Bit
DECLARE @ans bit  -- Declare a bit variable

IF exists( SELECT        SU_ID, SU_Email
       FROM            SystemUser
       WHERE        (SU_Email = @email)
       )
    Begin
       set @ans = 1
    END
else
    Begin
       set @ans = 0
    End

RETURNS @ans
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
DECLARE @FOUND INT
SET @FOUND = (SELECT COUNT(*) AS F FROM SystemUser WHERE (SU_Email = @email))
IF @FOUND > 0 THEN
 RETURN 0
ELSE
 RETURN -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to insert if not exists

```
 IF Not exists( SELECT * FROM  SystemUser  WHERE SU_Email = @email)
 Begin
     --Insert statment here
 END
```

Answer (score 1):

Define Unique as constraint in SQL Server datacolumn.
Handle exception for the same.